# How do I get Craft custom settings from inside a module?

Tags: config

Additional settings added to `config/general.php` are placed in `_customSettings` private object.

This means they cannot be retrieved using `Craft::$app->config->general->someCustomSetting`.

How can I access them?

Comment: The key you’ve got there should work. GeneralConfig has a [__get method](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/60a7777094d9ea78b851fd9164b2330c6645f0c8/src/config/GeneralConfig.php#L943) that specifically checks for _customSettings keys.